# Tricky real integral: $\int_0^{2 \pi} e^{\cos(2 t)} \cos(\sin(2 t)) =2\pi$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to prove the following:
$$ \int_0^{2 \pi} e^{\cos(2 t)} \cos(\sin(2 t))  =2\pi $$

Numerical analysis agrees with this to very high accuracy, so I'm almost sure it's true. Mathematica gives this answer after thinking for a long, but gives an insane antiderivative in terms of exponential integrals. I'd like to evaluate the integral with purely real methods (I've never done complex analysis), as elegantly as possible.

How can I tackle this integral?

Comment: Have you heard of Cauchy integral theorem?

Comment: It would appear that$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{\cos at}\cos(\sin at)\,\mathrm dt=2\pi$$at least for all non-zero integer values of $a$.

Comment: $x=cos(2t)$ then $dx=-2sin(2t)dt$ and the integral has to be broken up into four parts at intervals with $t=\frac{\pi}{2}$, each with integrand $\frac{1}{2}e^xcos(x)$.  Each piece should integrate to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: You may not have done "complex analysis", in the sense of things like the residue theorem, but I can offer you a one-line proof that in terms of complex numbers only uses $\exp ix=\cos x+i\sin x$, viz. $$\Re\int_0^{2\pi}\exp(\exp i2t)dt=\Re\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^{2\pi}\exp i2nt dt=\Re\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{2\pi\delta_{2n,\,0}}{n!}=2\pi.$$With a bit of care, you can use Taylor series to rewrite that as a real-only proof.

Answer (score 25):

Write

$$ I(\alpha) = \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{\alpha \cos(2t)}\cos(\alpha \sin(2t)) \, dt. $$

Then $I(0) = 2\pi$, and for $\alpha > 0$,

\begin{align*}
I'(\alpha)
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \left[ e^{\alpha \cos(2t)}\cos(\alpha \sin(2t))\cos(2t) - e^{\alpha \cos(2t)}\sin(\alpha \sin(2t))\sin(2t) \right] \, dt \\
&= \left[ \frac{1}{2\alpha} e^{\alpha\cos(2t)}\sin(\alpha\sin(2t)) \right]_{0}^{2\pi} \\
&= 0.
\end{align*}

So $I(\alpha) = 2\pi$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

---

**A general computation.** Let $f$ be analytic on $B(0,R)$. Define $I : [0, R) \to \mathbb{C}$ by

$$ I(r) = \int_{0}^{2\pi} f\left(re^{i\theta}\right) \, d\theta. $$

Then

$$ I'(r)
= \int_{0}^{2\pi} f'\left(re^{i\theta}\right)e^{i\theta} \, d\theta
= \left[ \frac{1}{ir} f\left(re^{i\theta}\right) \right]_{0}^{2\pi}
= 0 $$

and thus $I$ is constant with the value $I(0) = 2\pi f(0)$. The above answer corresponds to the real part of this computation with $f(z) = e^z$.

Answer (score 4):

*Assuming that you could enjoy special functions.*

Consider
$$I=\int e^{\cos(a t)} \cos(\sin(a t))\,dt\qquad \text{and}\qquad J=\int e^{\cos(a t)} \sin(\sin(a t))\,dt$$

$$I+iJ=\int e^{e^{ i at}}\,dt=-\frac{i}{a}\, \text{Ei}\left(e^{i a t}\right)$$
$$I-iJ=\int e^{e^{- ia t}}\,dt=\frac{i}{a} \, \text{Ei}\left(e^{- i a t}\right)$$ (where appear [the exponential integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral)) since, using $e^{kt}=u$,
$$\int e^{e^{kt}}\,dt=\frac{1}{k }\int\frac{e^u}{u}\,du=\frac{1}{k }\,\text{Ei}(u)$$ This makes
$$I=\frac{i }{2 a}\,\left(\text{Ei}\left(e^{-i a t}\right)-\text{Ei}\left(e^{i a
   t}\right)\right)$$
$$J=-\frac{1}{2 a}\,\left(\text{Ei}\left(e^{-i a t}\right)+\text{Ei}\left(e^{i a t}\right)\right)$$ For integer values of $a$, the definite integration from $0$ to $2\pi$ requires breaking it in $2a$ intervals and, as @user170231 commented, the result is $2\pi$ for any $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Put $z=e^{it}$ and using the formulas:
$$\cos{2t}=\frac{z^2+\frac{1}{z^2}}{2}$$

$$\sin{2t}=\frac{z^2-\frac{1}{z^2}}{2i}$$

apply the $\text{Residue theorem}$ integrating along the circle $C(0,1)=\{z:|z|=1\}$